# how use ghost brawser of facebook / webdriver in php's laravel

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I studying and using facebook/web driver in Laravel

all most are good working, but I want to use ghost browser.

I have redirected as a link for download ghost driver from selenium website, and I see this page

```
https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver
```

I don't know what to do after download as my project

I'm using PHP's Laravel framework

how binding this lib in my project?
please give me some advice

I'm not accustomed to English, so please understand if I make a mistake. and thank for reading my post.